# Measurable Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Suppose I have an operator valued function, $\omega\mapsto A(\omega)$; for each $\omega$, $A(\omega):X\to Y$, is a bounded linear operator with $X$ and $Y$ real Hilbert separable Hilbert spaces.  Suppose I know that for any $x,y$, $(A(\omega)x,y)$ is a measurable mapping from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.  Here $\mathcal{F}$ is some $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

Two questions:

Is it thus true that $\omega \mapsto L(\omega)$ is a measurable mapping from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(L(X,Y), \mathcal{B})$?  I am giving $L(X,Y)$ the operator norm topology, though perhaps this is true in some other topology.  I am also happy to make a separability assumption on $X$ and $Y$ if need be.

If it is true, how can I see this?

Comment: I do a sketch below.

Comment: I think you do need separability on both $X$ and $\mathscr{L}(X,Y)$ and that the two functions $\omega \mapsto (A(\omega) \cdot x \mid A(\omega) \cdot x)$ and $\omega \mapsto (A(\omega) \cdot x \mid y)$ be measurable for any choice of $x$ in $X$ and $y \in Y.$

Comment: I think this is false if $\mathcal L(X,Y)$ is not separable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathrm{B}$ be the ball of centre $f$ and radius $r > 0$ in the space of linear functions $X \to Y.$ You want to show $\{A \in \mathrm{B}\}$ is a measurable set (that is, belongs to $\mathscr{F}$). By definition, $A(\omega) \in \mathrm{B}$ is equivalent to $\|A(\omega) - f\| \leq r$ and this signifies
$$(A(\omega) \cdot x \mid A(\omega) \cdot x) - 2(A(\omega) \cdot x \mid f(x)) \leq r(x|x) - (f(x)|f(x))$$ for all $x \in \mathrm{X}.$

If $\mathrm{X}$ *were* separable, and $\mathrm{S}$ were a separating set for $\mathrm{X},$ then the condition:
$$(A(\omega) \cdot x \mid A(\omega) \cdot x) - 2(A(\omega) \cdot x \mid f(x)) \leq r(x|x) - (f(x)|f(x)) \quad (x \in \mathrm{X})$$
is equivalent to
$$(A(\omega) \cdot x \mid A(\omega) \cdot x) - 2(A(\omega) \cdot x \mid f(x)) \leq r(x|x) - (f(x)|f(x)) \quad (x \in \mathrm{S}).$$
Let $\mathrm{T}_x$ the set of $\omega$ satisfaying the previous inequality for $x.$ The extended hypotheses (in my comments) imply $\mathrm{T}_x$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}.$ Then $$\mathrm{T} = \bigcap_{x \in \mathrm{S}} \mathrm{T}_x \in \mathscr{F}.$$
This allows deducing $A$ is measurable. For we just showed $A^{-1}(\mathrm{B})$ is measurable for any ball, hence, if $\mathscr{L}(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y})$ *were* separable, $A^{-1}(\mathrm{U})$ would be measurable for any open set $\mathrm{U}$ in $\mathscr{L}(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y})$ (for the separability of $\mathscr{L}(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y})$ permits writting $\mathrm{U}$ as a countable union of balls). Having $A^{-1}(\mathrm{U})$ measurable for every open set $\mathrm{U},$ you can consider the set $\mathscr{Z}$ of Borel subsets $\mathrm{K}$ in $\mathscr{L}(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y})$ such that $A^{-1}(\mathrm{K})$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}.$ It is easy to see $\mathscr{Z}$ is a sigma algebra and we showed, under restrictive hypotheses, it contains the open sets, hence $\mathscr{Z}$ is all Borel sets. Q.E.D.

Comment: However, be warned that separability of $\mathscr{L}(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y})$ forces finite dimension in $\mathrm{X}$ and, perhaps, also in $\mathrm{Y}:$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119264/separability-of-the-space-of-bounded-operators-on-a-hilbert-space

Comment: I definitely don’t want finite dimensionslity

Comment: Read my proof, maybe you can come up with something simpler. It is possible, though, that you could change the topology of $\mathscr{L}(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y})$ and give (essentially) the same proof.

Answer (score 0):

I had another thought on this problem if I use a slightly different topology for $L(X,Y)$.  Instead of the looking at the topology induced by the Borel sets with respect to the operator, norm, consider the strong operator topology induced by the sets
$$
\{L \in L(X,Y): Lx \in B\}, \quad x \in X, \quad B \in \mathcal{B}(Y)
$$
Furthermore, assume that $Y$ is separable, with sequence $\{y_n\}$ such that
$$
\|y\|_Y = \sup_n |(y,y_n)_Y|
$$
For any $x\in X$, and $n=1,2,\ldots$, define
$$
a_{x,n}(\omega) = (A(\omega)x,y_n).
$$
By the assumption, the $a_{x,n}$ are measurable.  Now, if $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ and $r>0$,
$$
\begin{split}
A(\cdot)^{-1}(\{L \in L(X,Y): Lx \in B_r(y)\}) &= \{\omega: A(\omega)x \in B_r(y)\}\\
&=\{\omega: \|A(\omega)x - y\|_Y<r\}\\
&=\{\omega: \sup_{n}|(A(\omega)x - y,y_n)_Y|<r\}\\
&=\cap_{n=1}^\infty a_{x,n}^{-1}(B_r((y,y_n)))\in \mathcal{F}
\end{split}
$$
Since this holds for arbitrary balls $B_r(y)$, it will then apply to the case where $B\in \mathcal{B}(Y)$, and we have measurability in this weaker topology.

Thoughts?

I am still unsure if there is something to do I the operator norm topology.  I began thinking about this while reading Da Prato & Zabcyzk who remark that $L(X,Y)$ will not be separable, even if $X$ and $Y$ both are, and they provide a counterexample for $X=Y=L^2(\mathbb{R})$.